# Trigger Gitlab CI pipeline with personal token

Tags: gitlab

Is it possible to allow only authenticated users to trigger a Gitlab CI pipeline ?

The following works but the token is shared so it doesn't authentificate the user who make the curl:

> curl --globoff --request POST
>   "http://gitlab.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/123/ref/master/trigger/pipeline?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Answer (score 1):

```
curl -X POST 'https://gitlab.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/pipeline?ref=<ref-name>' \
-H 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your-private-token>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `manual actions`. To execute these you need merge rights to the executing branch. If you need for some reasons this behaviour only for specific branches you can use protected branches to limit the users further.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#manual-actions